# django drf left join

Tags: django, foreign-key-relationship, django-rest-framework

I have this model:

```
class Env(models.Model):
    env_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    is_enabled = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ENABLED, default='Y')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.env_name)
```

I also have this model ...

```
class Hosts(models.Model):
    host_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    host_variables = jsonfield.JSONField()
    host_env = models.ForeignKey(Env, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='host_env')
```

I wish to have a serialized representation equivalent to a join.

I'm trying to get rows that contain `host_name` and `env_name`

I can't seem to find the right way to serialize it

I'm  have so far ...

```
class HostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Hosts
    fields = ('host_name', 'ip_address', 'is_enabled','is_managed','managed_users')
```

I can't seem to find the right way to get the name of the env in each row of my Hosts results.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
class HostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer): 
    env_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='host_env.env_name')
    class Meta: 
        model = Hosts 
        fields = ('host_name', 'ip_address', 'is_enabled','is_managed','managed_users', 'env_name',)
```

Answer (score 2):

A serializer only handles a single Model, so anything else you want to add has to be added explicitly.

If you just want to add the env_name, you can use the `SerializerMethodField` field like this:

```
class HostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  env_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
  class Meta:
    model = Hosts
    fields = ('host_name', 'env_name', 'ip_address', 'is_enabled','is_managed',
              'managed_users',)

    def get_env_name(self, obj):
        host_env = obj.host_env
        if host_env:
            return str(host_env.env_name)
        return None
```

Note that you may also want to look into nested serializers, but that would produce something like:

```
{
    'host_name': 'my host name',
    'host_env': {
        'env_name': 'My env name'
    }
}
```

See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships for that (not explaining that as that was not your OP, but giving it to you as a reference for a potentially better way)